# Blit function in C++ (threading)

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have playing around with threading in C++ and I found some interesting results. The goal is to set image (2560x1440) completely in white -> array<int,3> {255,255,255}.
First run is single threaded.

Second and third run is 16 threaded (my machine can do it).

```
vector<array<int,3>> image { 2560*1440 };
// measure begins here ...
for (std::size_t i=0; i<1440; ++i)
  for (std::size_t j=0; j<2560; ++j)
    image[i*2560+j] = {255,255,255};
```

First threaded:

```
vector<array<int,3>> image { 2560*1440 };
auto n = thread::hardware_concurrency();
auto execution = [&](std::size_t id) {
  for (std::size_t i=0; i<1440; ++i)
    for (std::size_t j=id; j<2560; j+=n)
      image[i*2560+j] = {255,255,255};
};
```

Second threaded:

```
vector<array<int,3>> image { 2560*1440 };
auto n = thread::hardware_concurrency();
auto execution = [&](std::size_t id) {
  for (std::size_t i=id; i<1440; i+=n)
    for (std::size_t j=0; j<2560; ++j)
      image[i*2560+j] = {255,255,255};
};
```

The performance of the third one is dramatically better:

- Single: 28076 microseconds
- First threaded: 24688 microseconds
- second threaded: 4073 microseconds

Can somebody explain me, why it is so dramatically better? Is it because there are less pointer "movements"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first threaded example, you go line by line and jump `n` pixels in that line. Thus reading is not sequential and caching gets harder for the CPU.

In the second threaded example, you jump lines by `n` but access the pixels sequentially, resulting in less cache misses and improving performance.